# PHP print dropdown list and select from the middle by default

Tags: php, postgresql, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list that works fine, but halfway through the list of 80 values is the one I want as selected by default

```
$cosOptions = cos_options();
```

Is the variable

```
<td><select name="options"><?php print $cosOptions; ?></select></td>
```

Prints the dropdown, then the function below.

```
function cos_options()
{
    $dbh = dbh_get();
    $options = '';

    $sql = 'select code, descr FROM cos';
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    while (true) {
        $r = $stmt->fetch();
        if (is_bool($r)) break;
        $options .= '<option value="' . $r['code'] . ' ' . $r['descr'] . '">' . $r['code'] . ' ' . $r['descr'] . '</option>';
    }

    dbh_free($dbh);
    return $options;
}
```

The Postgres table only has two columns and 80 rows

**code    descr**

D1    Pizza

D2    Bread

D3    Cornflakes etc,.

What I need is **D43    Rice** to be selected at first because 90% of the time it will be this. How can I achieve this? I've gone through a bunch of posts on here but can't get it working.

Comment: if you are sure with value D43, when you reach it, adding `selected="selected" in option should do it

Comment: @OldPadawan how could I do that? Can you give me an example please?

Comment: let's say `$r['code'] = D43` then `ìf ($mycode == "D43") { $selected = "selected='selectded'"; } else { $selected = ""; }` and in `$options .= '<option value="' . $r['code'] . ' ' . $r['descr'] . '" $selected>' . $r['code'] . ' ' . $r['descr'] . '</option>'; ` see answer

Comment: answer done, please check and see ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function cos_options()
{
$dbh = dbh_get();
$options = '';

$sql = 'select code, descr FROM cos';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
while (true) {
    $r = $stmt->fetch();
    if (is_bool($r)) break;
    $temp=$r['code']. ' '. $r['descr'];
    if($temp=="D43 Rice") //check for whatever you want to set selected
    {
    $options .= '<option selected value="' . $r['code'] . ' ' . $r['descr'] . '">' . $r['code'] . ' ' . $r['descr'] . '</option>';
    }
    else
    {
    $options .= '<option value="' . $r['code'] . ' ' . $r['descr'] . '">' . $r['code'] . ' ' . $r['descr'] . '</option>';
    } 
}

dbh_free($dbh);
return $options;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code which select D43Rice option value select. do not use D43 Rice and merge D43Rice , sometime text space will add

```
<?php
while (true) {
    $r = $stmt->fetch();
    if (is_bool($r)) {
        break;
    }
    $selected = '';
    if ($r['code'].$r['descr'] == 'D43Rice') {
        $selected = 'selected="selected"';
    }
    $options .= '<option "' . $selected . '" value="' . $r['code'] . ' ' . $r['descr'] . '">' . $r['code'] . ' ' . $r['descr'] . '</option>';
}
?>
```

this is update condition which check code value

```
<?php
while (true) {
    $r = $stmt->fetch();
    if (is_bool($r)) {
        break;
    }
    $selected = $r['code'].$r['descr'] = 'D43Rice' ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
    $options .= '<option "' . $selected . '" value="' . $r['code'] . ' ' . $r['descr'] . '">' . $r['code'] . ' ' . $r['descr'] . '</option>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

if ($whateveryourneededcodeis == "D43") 
{
$selected = 'selected="selected"';
} else {
$selected = '';
}

$options .= '<option value="'.$r['code'].''.$r['descr'].'" $selected>'
.$r['code'].''.$r['descr'].'
</option>';

?>
```